# sqlite database version not getting set - android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to set the version number of my sqlite database, because I would like to upgrade it in the OnUpgrade method of my SQLiteHelper class. My helper class constructor is the following:

```
public DataBaseHelper(Context context){
super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
}
```

However, when I check the version of the database in the "openDataBase()" method, the version number is 0. What gives?

Comment: Ah! I found the problem-silly me. In my openDataBase() method, I was not instantiating my database from the DataBaseHelper constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: I needed to instantiate my database from the constructor.

Comment: Hi I am having exactly the same problem. My db version is always 0. How do I ensure that the version is brought inline with the version of my helper? I'm not quite sure what you mean by the above...